# Is Bottom sheet Available for pre-lollipop Devices?

Tags: android, material-design, androiddesignsupport

Is there any component available like Bottom sheet in appcompat-v7  or design  support library?
So I can use in pre-Lollipop device.
I don't want to use any other libraries like,

https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet

https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

https://github.com/ifwe/android-material-bottom-sheet

https://github.com/ifwe/android-material-bottom-sheet?files=1

https://github.com/Collaborne/paper-bottom-sheet

Thnx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because New Update of Design support library fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Now it's available in [Android Design Support Library v23.2.0](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/QFtt71VUgsB)

Comment: Yes, Latest design support library include classes for Bottom sheet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any component available like Bottom sheet in appcompat-v7 or design support library?

Not at this time.

> I don't want to use any other libraries like

Then you will have to write your own bottom sheet implementation, or not use a bottom sheet.